# onmouseout on select option element

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a requirement in which i have to display alternate elements depending upon mouseover and mouseout events.

Default element is a hyperlink( it will be displayed all times except at onmouseover) and the alternate element is a Drop down list  element(it should be displayed on mouseover of the hyperlink.

I am using javascript to toggle the display(hide/unhide) of the two elements.

The problem is the scope of mouse is limited to the select element only and not its options values i.e when i try to select the option values from the DDL using mouse the browser thinks it as mouseout and it toggles the element.I want that mouseout should not happen even when im running my mouse over the drop down list option elements.Is there anyway to fix this?

Here is what i have written so far.

JS code

```
function showDDl()
{
  document.getElementById("LINK").style.display='none';
  document.getElementById("ddlLanguage").style.display='';
}
function hideDDl()
{
  document.getElementById("ddlLanguage").style.display='none';
  document.getElementById("LINK").style.display='';
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<!--CODE FOR Hyperlink.. this is to be displayed at all times except at mouseover -->
<div id="LINK">
<a href='#' onmouseover="showDDl()" >
(Change Language)
</a>
</div>

<!--CODE FOR SELECT ELEMENT dispalyed at mouseover -->

<select style="display: none;" id="ddlLanguage" name="ddlLanguage" onmouseout="hideDDl()">
  <option value="en"><bean:message key="common.lang.english"/></option>
  <option value="fr"><bean:message key="common.lang.francais"/></option>
  <option value="de"><bean:message key="common.lang.deutsch"/></option>
  <option value="it"><bean:message key="common.lang.italiano"/></option>
  <option value="es"><bean:message key="common.lang.espanol"/></option>
  <option value="nl"><bean:message key="common.lang.nederlands"/></option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you are going to manipulate DOM objects why not use Jquery? you would just need 3 lines ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

- Wrap the Dropdown in another div. This `div` should have the `mouseout`, not the select
- Add a cancelbubble / stopPropogation to the mouseout on the select, to prevent the select from disappearing when it is open.
- Add an onchanged handler to the select to close the drop down when an item is selected.

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WaddN/)

```
<div id="DROPDOWN"  onmouseout="hideDDl()">
    <select style="display: none;" 
            id="ddlLanguage" 
            name="ddlLanguage" 
            onmouseout="cancelBubble();" 
            onchange="hideDDl();">
        <option value="en">
       ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a handler for a `mouseout` event and check a target element (`event.target` or `event.srcElement` for IE). If it isn't a list element then call `hideDDl`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking out for this. Try it

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function showDDl()
 {
    // alert("p");
   document.getElementById("LINK").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("ddlLanguage").style.visibility="visible";

 }
 function hideDDl()
 {
   document.getElementById("ddlLanguage").style.visibility="hidden";
     document.getElementById("LINK").style.visibility="visible";
 }
</script>

HTML CODE

<!--CODE FOR Hyperlink.. this is to be displayed at all times except at mouseover -->

<a href='#' onMouseOver="showDDl()" id="LINK" >
(Change Language)
</a>
<br/>

<!--CODE FOR SELECT ELEMENT dispalyed at mouseover -->

<select style="visibility:hidden" id="ddlLanguage" name="ddlLanguage" onmouseout="hideDDl()">
  <option value="en"><bean:message key="common.lang.english"/></option>
  <option value="fr"><bean:message key="common.lang.francais"/></option>
  <option value="de"><bean:message key="common.lang.deutsch"/></option>
  <option value="it"><bean:message key="common.lang.italiano"/></option>
  <option value="es"><bean:message key="common.lang.espanol"/></option>
  <option value="nl"><bean:message key="common.lang.nederlands"/></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im still not unable to hold the options list of the select element, as soon as i move my mouse down the list it hides or changes its style to hidden. :(. I try my luck with jquery

Comment: A better way is make the select option disabled by default.When you hover the mouse on the link, the select option will be enabled.And onselect an option it will again show the link